# Update records in Table1 based on duplicates in Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to work on this for some days already and I can't find a proper solution.

I've 2 tables:

-Adgroups: Contains a list of adgroups with their uniqueAdgroupID and the AdgroupName. This table has duplicated names.

-Adgroup_Campaigns: Contains a list of campaigns with an uniqueCampaignID, and a uniqueAdgroupId from table1.

What I need to do is to find all duplicated names in table Adgroups, which I do with the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.[AdGroup_Id], o.[AdGroup]
FROM (
    SELECT [AdGroup], COUNT(*) as intCount
    FROM [dbo].[AdGroup]
    GROUP BY [AdGroup]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
AS d
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AdGroup] o ON o.[AdGroup] = d.[AdGroup]
```

This returns a list like:

```
Adgroup_Id   AdGroup      
----------- ----------
1           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2      
2           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2      
5           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2       
6           UNI-A-v2-LP2
8           UNI-A-v2-LP2
10          UNI-A-v2-LP2
16          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2
17          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2
20          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2
```

Now I cross check in the Table Adgroup_Campaigns all records which AdGroupId is in the list of duplicated adgroups, which I do with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT
        o.[AdGroup_Id], o.[AdGroup]
    FROM (
        SELECT [AdGroup], COUNT(*) as intCount
        FROM [dbo].[AdGroup]
        GROUP BY [AdGroup]
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
    AS d
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AdGroup] o ON o.[AdGroup] = d.[AdGroup]
)
AS x INNER JOIN [dbo].[AdGroupCampaignMapper] t
ON t.[AdGroup_Id] = x.[AdGroup_Id]
```

Which returns a list like:

```
Adgroup_Id   AdGroup         Campaign_Id      
----------- ---------        ------------
1           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  1    
2           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  3    
5           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  5     
6           UNI-A-v2-LP2     6
8           UNI-A-v2-LP2     7
10          UNI-A-v2-LP2     8
16          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   9
17          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   10
20          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   11
```

So what I need is a query that will actually update the fields Adgroup_Id in table Adgroup_Campaigns so each group of duplicates have as Adgroup_Id the first ID of that group like so:

```
Adgroup_Id   AdGroup         Campaign_Id      
----------- ---------        ------------
1           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  1    
1           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  3    
1           PRE-MAS--v2-LP2  5     
6           UNI-A-v2-LP2     6
6           UNI-A-v2-LP2     7
6           UNI-A-v2-LP2     8
16          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   9
16          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   10
16          PRE-UNI-v2-LP2   11
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an update  with inner join

```
update  a 
set  AdGroupCampaignMapper.Adgoup_Id = t.min_id
FROM  [dbo].[AdGroupCampaignMapper]  as a
INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT  [AdGroup] , min([AdGroup_Id]) min_id, COUNT(*) as intCount
        FROM [dbo].[AdGroup]
        GROUP BY [AdGroup]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  ) t on . t.AdGroup = a.AdGroup
```

Comment: Thanks but that actually doesn't work, that will select the minimum AdGroup_Id from all the AdGroups and put it in all the campaigns (did the test myself).

Comment: @victorgonal   ... i'm sorry wrong column .. i have update the answer using Adgroup_id